Circles with large radii are plotted with fuzzy edges. Why? Is this documented?
When viewing 2D circles in Mathematica with radius greater that 3000 increasing to a million, inside a plot range of 20 by 20, the edge of the circle is plotted as an ever widening gray band. As if Mathematica is uncertain as to the actual location as is hence graying smearing it out. This code reproduces the problem:
Manipulate[
 Column[{2^x, 
   Graphics[{Circle[{-2^x, -2^x}, 2^(x + 1/2)]}, PlotRange -> 20, 
    ImageSize -> 600]}],
 {{x, 1}, 1, 24}]

Here is the result with slider part way:

I don't necessarily need a solution. I could replace the circle with a line. I just want to know if this behavior is intentional and/or documented.
Version info Mathematica 14.0, on Mac OS 14.5

I do not see any blurred edges. V 14.1 on windows 10. Can you post screen shot? Better use PlotRange->All to see the whole circle otherwise it will get cutoff as you change the slider. https://i.sstatic.net/WxZRk4pw.png

Reproduced in "14.1.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 16, 2024)". Becomes fuzzy around x=15.

Confirm @Nasser.

I cannot reproduce what it sounds like is happening here ("12.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)"), but a screen shot would be useful to make sure.

If you use "PlotRange->All" it wont happen. You have to be zoomed into a very small portion of the circle (like 1/10000 of its circumference). I don't see how to attach screen shot to this comment at the moment, but will when I do figure it out.

Oh, and I should have said: this in 14.0, on Mac OS 14.5

On 13.0.1 everything is fine.

For a radius around 700000, it alternates between a gray square and a sharp line as I scroll the window. Does the FE recalculate the window view when a window is scrolled, or does the OS handle the whole thing? Saving the gray square as a PNG yields an image with a sharp, black line.

Identical codes, different renderings (Mac M1, V14.1): https://i.sstatic.net/bzFJpAUr.png
